# What does it mean when you say 'What I wouldn't give to be there?

Tags: sentence, sentence-patterns

I was watching tv, and a guy was talking about outer space and said this sentence.

What does it mean when you say 'What I wouldn't give to...?'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a less dramatic version of the doubtless hyperbolic

> "I'd give my right arm [/hand] to be there."

(See, for example, [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/give-your-right-arm))

The implication is that you'd give up many of your prized possessions / comforts in return for being there (etc).

"What [*is there* that] I wouldn't give [up] to be able to ...?" [implication: the list of what I **wouldn't** give up in exchange is small]

..................

[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/what-i-wouldn-t-give-for-sth) actually gives the expression:

> **what I wouldn't give for something** (also what wouldn't I give for something)
>
> used to say that you want something very much:
>
> *What I wouldn't give for a cold drink!*